# Passport authentication unique session id concept

Tags: javascript, authentication, passport.js

So the idea from what I understand is that Passport will generate a unique session id for any user even if they're unauthenticated. Once they authenticate, the server can associate a userId (usually from the database) to this session id.

I'm looking at the code and it looks like passport.serialize stores userId inside a session and then passport.deserialize takes the userid that's stored in the session and queries the database for more user information

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id)
      .then(user => done(null, user))
      .catch(err => done(err));
});
```

What I don't really see is the unique sessionId. If the userId is stored in a session then can't anyone spoof the userId and grab user information? Or is the mapping between sessionId and userId executed under the hood by Passport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under normal conditions, Passport creates the unique session key and then encrypts it with the secret you provide when configuring it on app start.  The encrypted form of that key gets sent to the client as a cookie header, which is computationally expensive for a client to crack.

When the client sends that cookie back in the next request, Passport extracts the stored session key from the cookie by using the same secret to decrypt it, and then it passes that value to your deserializeUser callback to get whatever associated info you have.

Some of the details in this vary with certain Strategies (e.g. JWT strategy doesn't use cookies, it uses the JWT token itself sent as a header), but the general pattern is the same.